# What would be the best way to handle APNS 0 - Byte response - Technical Note tn2265

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

In the technical note, [tn2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG44) apple describes how to handle errors while attempting to send batch push notifications: (direct quote)

> Here's how to check for errors when using the enhanced notification
>   format. Keep writing until a write fails. If the stream is ready for
>   writing again, resend the notification and keep going. If the stream
>   isn't ready for writing, see if the stream is available for reading.
>
> If it is, read everything available from the stream. ***If you get zero
>   bytes back, the connection was closed because of an error such as an
>   invalid command byte or other parsing error***. If you get six bytes
>   back, that's an error response that you can check for the response
>   code and the ID of the notification that caused the error. You'll need
>   to send every notification following that one again.

My question relates to the text I have highlighted in bold. For the record, I am using the Enhanced Notification Format, and I am passing in my unique ID for each recipient in the my list, so as the APNS service can return this id in case of errors.

In case we receive 0 bytes back, i.e. Apple has closed the connection without sending an error code back, we cannot know after which attempted device token the error occurred. I.e. we cannot resume sending from that or the next token.

In this case, is it acceptable to attempt re-sending to all the devices again? Is this not going to result in devices being "*spammed*" by the same notification multiple times?

For example: Assume I have a list of 5000 devices to send to. The ***0-byte response*** problem occurs after I have successfully sent to a random part of my list, and I do not know how many devices AND which ones have actually received my notification. Not having an error code returned with the device id of the last successful device, or the device at which the error occurred, does not allow me to resume sending from the next token, which was the whole purpose behind using the Enhanced Notification Format in the first place.

How have others handled this issue? I would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Has no one else had this issue? I still have not found a solution to this, and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Just for clarification, I am now throwing an exception when I attempt to read the socket and receive a 0 byte response (i.e. socket has been closed from remote host), and since I cannot know at which device token the error occurred, I attempt to re-send to the whole list. As a result, now all devices in my list receive the push - AT LEAST - once, with some devices receiving it twice, as I had expected...